# Adding Azure Single-Sign-On to an existing MVC application, in VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013, single-sign-on

I've been exploring the Azure Active Directory services and was pleased with how easy it was to hook up an arbitrary ASP.NET MVC website to it. I've experimented with this in Visual Studio 2012 and all works well. Especially using the [Identity and Access Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e) extension for VS2012.

Now here comes the tricky part: This tool is however deprecated and not supported on, nor available for Visual Studio 2013.

There are several MSDN documents on the matter, [like this excellent tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn151790.aspx), only I find them all targeting VS2012 and the forementioned tool. For new projects the process is "simplified when creating a new web application". But I don't want a new application - I want to hook up existing applications in VS2013.

Now the question is: is there a 'decent' way to integrate Azure ActiveDirectory, especially the Single Sign-On feature, to an **existing ASP.NET MVC 5** web application in Visual Studio 2013?

At least with the same ease as the I&A Tool, but without the need to recreate or migrate my entire application, of course.

Comment: **Hypothetically speaking** there could be a non-supported workaround where you can download the VSIX for the Identity & Access tool, extract it as a zip, modify the .manifest file to support Visual Studio 12.0 instead of 11.0 (12 == VS2013), pack it again as zip, rename to .vsix... And perhaps you could install it in VS2013 to make it work. Of course, if this would work, it'd be a direct violation of the EULA. If only it was open source #sigh

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your project, you can either create a new project and import your project files to the new project or import the identity settings to your existing project.

Since the identity controls are really just a set of files and configuration, you should be able to create a project with the identity settings you want and then copy over the files / configuration to your existing project. You may also need to add references to things like `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` and any security providers you need. Files to take a look at include:

- `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs`
- `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`
- `Controllers/AccountController.cs`
- `Startup.cs`
- `Web.config`

Yes, it's a pain, and hopefully there will be an easier way of adding or changing identity later, but this is the best I've come up with for now.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out as well. But exactly like you're mentioning this is both a pain as well as simply ridiculous that you need to create a new project and manually start copy/paste files in order to achieve this. However, let's hope this will get some support in the near future.